# NameError at/ name 'Product' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I've been working on this eCommerce website and its been working perfectly but today when I ran the server it's showed me " NameError at/ name '

> Product' is not defined

"
I've looked Into the code several times and didn't spot any error

Models.py

```
Class Product(models.Model):
   ""
   ""
   def __str__(self)
      self.name
```

Views.py

```
From .models import *
def ShowProducts(request):
   items= Product.objects.all()
   context = {'items':items}
   return render(request, 'home.html', context=context)
```

urls.py

```
from . import views

urlspatterns=[
     Path ('', views.ShowProducts, name ='showproducts')
]
```

My greatest surprise is , when I change the line, `item= Product.objects.all()` to `items= ()` in views.py,. It displays the website correctly although without any product in it, please what should I do

Comment: Please post the call stack.

Comment: `Class` should be `class`

Comment: `Views.py` could be `views.py` too. Impossible to know :(

Comment: Is that your complete model? Where is the name property that you are calling in __str__? You should have a property that looks like `name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, null=True)` then run a migration

Answer (score 1):

There could be 2 reasons.

1. In the code `From .models import *` the From should be from. F is capital.
2. Models file path in `from .models import *` maybe `from ..models import *` is the correct path.

If you can share the directory structure then it may help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem:

Ideally, I believe the error you might be getting is:

```
NameError: name 'product' is not defined
```

#### Solution

This means that you should have a `product` attribute or alternatively, you may not have run the necessary migrations for your app.

Please add the attributes/fields that your require in your Product class(note that class begins with lower-case `c` in python, i.e `class Product`) & then run the migrations.
Your Product class seems to be lacking. Update it accordingly.

```
class Product(models.Model):
   # insert your fields here eg as below
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   def __str__(self)
      self.name
```

Comment: Yesssss...I just remembered I didn't run migration after adding image... thanks

Comment: No worries. That's understandable. Accept the answer if you found it useful.